# Pomodoro timer in Go

Tags: beginner, go, timer

My goal is to implement a simple [pomodoro timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) using Go: channels, goroutines.

I'm a newbie in Go world and have some misunderstanding about naming convention. I read a lot of Docker's code on GitHub and there I saw that people sometimes use very short names. These names are not clear for me (a man who comes from C++ world).

```
func main() {
   app := pomodoro.NewPomodoro()
   app.Start()
}
```

Give me a review about structure's name

```
type (
    PomodoroManager struct {
        dur    Duration
        interv Interval
        ch     Chanel
        serv   PomodoroService
    }

    Duration struct {
         working    int
         shortBreak int
         longBreak  int
    }

    Interval struct {
        shortInterval int
        longInterval  int
    }

    Chanel struct {
        start         chan bool
        endShortBreak chan bool
        endLongBreak  chan bool
        end           chan bool
    }
)

func NewPomodoro() *PomodoroManager {
    dur := Duration{
        working:    25,
        shortBreak: 5,
        longBreak:  15,
    }

    interv := Interval{
        shortInterval: 1,
        longInterval:  5,
    }

    ch := Chanel{
        start:         make(chan bool),
        endShortBreak: make(chan bool),
        endLongBreak:  make(chan bool),
        end:           make(chan bool),
    }

    serv := PomodoroService{}

    return &PomodoroManager{dur, interv, ch, serv}
}

func (p *PomodoroManager) Start() {
    go p.serv.StartWorking(p.ch.start, p.dur.working)
    go p.startServManager(p.ch.start, p.ch.endShortBreak, p.ch.endLongBreak, p.ch.end)

    <-p.ch.end
}

func (p *PomodoroManager) startServManager(start, endBreak, endLong, end chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case afterWorking := <-start:
            _ = afterWorking
            if p.interv.shortInterval == p.interv.longInterval {
                go p.serv.StartLongBreak(endLong, p.dur.longBreak)
            } else {
                p.interv.shortInterval += 1
                go p.serv.StartBreak(endBreak, p.dur.shortBreak)
            }
        case endShortRelax := <-endBreak:
            _ = endShortRelax
            go p.serv.StartWorking(start, p.dur.working)

        case endLongRelax := <-endLong:
            _ = endLongRelax

            userAnswer := askUser()
            if userAnswer == "Y" {
                p.interv.shortInterval = 1
                go p.serv.StartWorking(start, p.dur.working)
            } else {
                end <- true
            }
        }
    }
}

func askUser() string {
    fmt.Println("Do you want to coninue? Y/N")

    var answer string
    fmt.Scanln(&answer)

    return answer
}
```

And Last component of the program.

```
import (
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

type (
    Service interface {
        StartWorking(chan bool, int)
        FinishBreak(chan bool, int)
        FinishLongBreak(chan bool, int)
    }

    PomodoroService struct {
    }
)

func (p *PomodoroService) StartWorking(start chan bool, duration int) {
    exec.Command("say", "Start working").Output()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(duration))
    exec.Command("say", "Time to Relax").Output()
    start <- true
}

func (p *PomodoroService) StartBreak(endBreak chan bool, duration int) {
    exec.Command("say", "Start short relax").Output()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(duration))
    exec.Command("say", "Relax has finished, getting back to job").Output()
    endBreak <- true
}

func (p *PomodoroService) StartLongBreak(endLong chan bool, duration int) {
    exec.Command("say", "Start long relax").Output()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(duration))
    exec.Command("say", "Long pause has finished").Output()
    endLong <- true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I hope you get some nice answers.

Comment: Where is the tomato? :(

Answer (score 3):

Your `NewPomodoro` function should simply be called `New` (the fact that you're creating a Pomodoro thing is inherent in "you're calling `pomodoro.New`" and "there's only one New", if there were more, it would make sense to have, say, `NewTimer` and `NewManager`).

I don't see what the `PomodoroService` is actually useful for, it seems to be abstraction for the sake of abstraction. I would simply put the `StartBreak`, `StartLongBreak`, and `StartWorking` methods directly on the timer/manager, as long as this is essentially all there is.

I would probably have called `PomodoroManager` something else. Probably `Pomodoro`, `PomodoroTimer` or (most probably) just `Timer` (the fact that it's a Pomodoro timer is inherent from being in the `pomodoro` package).

I am ambivalent about having the various timers and channels in sub-structs. There's few enough that I am not 100% sure not doing so makes the code mode readable. However, since the members are not exported, their types do not need to be exported, since they can't be accessed from outside the package anyway. I would also name the structs in plural, since they clearly contain "channelS", "durationS" and "intervalS".

Since you're never seemingly using the values passed across your channels, you might as well make then `chan struct{}` instead of `chan bool`.

I would consider making your intervals to be of type `time.Duration` instead of `int`.

I would consider wrapping all the `exec.Command("say", ...).Output()"` calls in a non-exported utility function (called, say, `say`).

Answer (score 1):

I took a moment to rewrite your proposal to give you an alternative to compare with.

In this version the Timer consumes a length indefinite list of task (a channel),
context are used extensively to solve timeout management and exit sequences.
The switching to short/long break is a simple modulo statement of a counter.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Pomodoro struct {
    Task       chan Task
    ShortBreak Task
    LongBreak  Task
}

// Run loops until Pomodoro.Task channel is closed or the context is cancelled.
func (p Pomodoro) Run(ctx context.Context) {
    var i int
    // loop forever
    for {
        // wait for a task or exit
        var task Task
        var ok bool
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case task, ok = <-p.Task:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
        //run the task
        p.doTask(ctx, task)
        //increment the current counter
        i++
        // Once in a while, perform a long break
        if i%4 == 0 {
            p.doTask(ctx, p.LongBreak)
            continue
        }
        // otherwise, make a short break
        p.doTask(ctx, p.ShortBreak)
    }
}

//doTask execute a task until the context was cancelled or the timeout expired
func (p Pomodoro) doTask(ctx context.Context, task Task) {
    if task.Do == nil {
        return
    }
    // setup a cancellable context
    taskCtx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    // with a deadline, if any
    if task.Timeout > 0 {
        taskCtx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, task.Timeout)
    }
    // start the task
    go func() {
        task.Do(taskCtx)
        cancel()
    }()
    // wait for the context to end
    <-taskCtx.Done()
}

// Task is a function with a timeout. Timeout can be set to zero for a task without deadline.
type Task struct {
    Do      func(ctx context.Context)
    Timeout time.Duration
}

func main() {

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    // setup the timer
    var timer Pomodoro
    timer.Task = make(chan Task)
    // short/long break are regular task.
    timer.ShortBreak = Task{
        Timeout: time.Second,
        Do: func(_ context.Context) {
            log.Println("short break")
        },
    }
    timer.LongBreak = Task{
        Timeout: 0, // this task does not use a deadline, it waits for the input.
        Do: func(_ context.Context) {
            fmt.Println("Do you want to continue? Y/N")
            var answer string
            fmt.Scanln(&answer)
            if answer != "Y" {
                // cancel the context to trigger exit sequence
                cancel()
            }
        },
    }

    // push your tasks
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            e := i
            timer.Task <- Task{
                Timeout: time.Second * 5,
                Do: func(ctx context.Context) {
                    w := time.Second*3 + time.Second*time.Duration(e)
                    log.Printf("begin task #%v, wait=%v\n", e, w)
                    select {
                    case <-time.After(w):
                        log.Printf("task #%v done\n", e)
                    case <-ctx.Done():
                        log.Printf("task #%v not ended quick enough", e)
                    }
                },
            }
        }
        close(timer.Task) // close this channel to trigger exit sequence.
    }()

    // wait on the timer to finish
    timer.Run(ctx)
    log.Println("all done.")
}
```